# T-SQL syntax issue with "LTRIM(RTRIM())" not working correctly

Tags: t-sql, trim, spaces

What is wrong with this statement that it is still giving me spaces after the field. This makes me think that the syntax combining the WHEN statements is off. My boss wants them combined in one statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
Case WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(cSHortName))= '' Then NULL 
     WHEN cShortname is NOT NULL THEN 
       REPLACE (cShortName,SUBSTRING,(cShortName,PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9""},1,) ''_ 
end AS SHORT_NAME
```

Comment: Sorry hand type the code in and fat fingered. It is 
ase WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(cSHortName))= '' Then NULL 
     WHEN cShortname is NOT NULL THEN 
       REPLACE (cShortName,SUBSTRING,(cShortName,PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9""},1,) ''_ 
end AS SHORT_NAME

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code, it seems that you may be trying to strip spaces and non-alphanumeric characters from the beginning and ending of the string.

If so, would this work for you?
I think it provides the substring from the first alphanumeric occurrence to the last.

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(
 cShortName,
 PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9',cShortName),
  ( LEN(cShortName)
   -PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9',REVERSE(cShortName))
   -PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9',cShortName)
  )
) AS SHORTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it is supposed not to give you spaces after the field?

Edit:

As far as I understand you are trying to remove any characters from the string that do not match this regular expression range [a-zA-Z0-9] (add any other characters that you want to preserve).

I see no clean way to do that in Microsoft SQL Server (you are using Microsoft SQL Server it seems) using the built-in functions. There are some examples on the web that use a temporary table and a while loop, but this is ugly. I would either return the strings as is and process them on the caller side, or write a function that does that using the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and invoke it from the select statement.

I hope this helps.

Comment: LTRIM(str): Removes all white spaces from the beginning of the string.
RTRIM(str): Removes all white spaces at the end of the string.
The two used in conjunction with each other is the equivalent of TRIM

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi akonsu, I am trying to remove all spaces around the field I am bringing into a new file from an old table that had no edits and has spaces on either the right, left or both. The second WHEN statement is to remove ASCII characters that do not display as results in the output but are definitely there. The characters I see most of is .... like someone has hit the space bar several times or it is an ellipsis and it seems like a carriage return. Most often it is the ellipsis ....

Comment: For the record, `LTRIM()` does not "remove all white spaces".  It removes leading spaces, but does nothing to tabs, line breaks, or other whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `TRIM` with `LTRIM`.

You can also test `LEN(cShortName) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Ummm there seems to be some problems in this script, but try this.

```
Case 
     WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(cSHortName))= '' Then NULL
     WHEN cShortname is NOT NULL THEN REPLACE(cShortName, SUBSTRING(cShortName, PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9', 1) , ''), '') 
end AS SHORT_NAME
```

Comment: tried this & got this error:
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of patindex function.

Comment: As OMGPonies indicated, try replacing it with PATINDEX('%A-Za-z0-9""}', cShortName)